# <div> tag in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I had quote generator project and I needed to include it in react-native project, but I don't know how to use . how can i fix this? How can I write this  section as react native?

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
       
      <div class="row p-2 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

      <textarea readOnly class="quote" id="input"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-2"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
   
    
     <button id="copy">Copy</button><br></br>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="tweetButton">Tweet</button>
   <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>

   <script src="getQuote.js"></script>
```

Quote Generator codes...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var randomQuote, randomAuthor;

getQuote();

function getQuote(){

var quotes = ["It’s not my fault.", "Your focus determines your 
  reality.", "Do. Or do not. There is no try.", 
 "In my experience there is no such thing as luck.", "Fear leads to 
  anger, anger leads to hate, hate leads to suffering.", 
 "Women always figure out the truth. Always."]
  var authors = ["- Han Solo", "– Qui-Gon Jinn", "-Yoda", "- Obi-Wan 
  Kenobi", "-Yoda", "- Han Solo"]

var number = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
randomQuote = quotes[number];
randomAuthor = authors[number];

$(".quote").text(randomQuote);
//$(".author").text(randomAuthor);
```

};

```
function copy() {
var copyText = document.querySelector("#input");
copyText.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML="copied";
```

}

```
var el = document.getElementById('copy');
if(el){
el.addEventListener('click', copy);
```

}

```
$("#quoteButton").on("click", function(){ 
getQuote();
```

});

Comment: Please take a look at the preview below before you ask a question. You have formatting problems.

Comment: there is no <div> in react native. There is instead <View>

Comment: Yup. That's why I asked. How do I fix the div part.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<View>      
      <View>
          <View>
           <Text></Text>
          </View>
      
      <View></View>
     
      </View>
   
    
     <Button >Copy</Button>
     <Button>Tweet</Button>
</View>
```

Check the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis)